Search box results are not shown in web
I have created a search box. In the box if I input any number then it searches all data between 2 Google Sheets and returns the results. Now the search is executing properly and clud is getting proper data but the data is not displayed in the web. I am using this search box in a google site. I developed the code with the help of ChatGPT and unable to understand why the results are not showing.
This is my code.gs
function searchSheets(contactNumber) {
var oldSheetId = '15cX2CuPCic21X4v2twgfLWi6_FN455tWyPORZUieqPk';
var newSheetId = '1VC6L6e-xMQ2CTbLR8SSOMug6GxqWPATcCtaVgUSll54';

var oldSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(oldSheetId).getSheetByName('OLD');
var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSheetId).getSheetByName('2024');

var oldData = oldSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var newData = newSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var combinedData = oldData.concat(newData);

var filteredData = combinedData.filter(function(row) {
return row[5].toString() === contactNumber.toString();
  });

Logger.log('Filtered Data: ' + JSON.stringify(filteredData));

return filteredData;
}

function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

This is my index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
function searchContact() {
const contactNumber = document.getElementById('contactNumber').value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayResults).searchSheets(contactNumber);
    }

function displayResults(data) {
console.log('Received data:', data); // Add this for debugging
const resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
resultsDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results

if (data.length === 0) {
resultsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>No results found.</p>';
return;
      }

const table = document.createElement('table');
table.border = 1;

const headers = [
        'Timestamp', 'Submitted By', 'Type of Request', 'Update For (LM Name/Team Name)', 
        'Customer Name', 'Customer Mobile No', 'Query Type', 'Lead Number', 
        'Remarks', 'Source Name', 'Location Name'
      ];

const headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
headers.forEach(header => {
const th = document.createElement('th');
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(header));
headerRow.appendChild(th);
      });
table.appendChild(headerRow);

data.forEach(row => {
const rowElement = document.createElement('tr');
row.forEach(cell => {
const cellElement = document.createElement('td');
cellElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cell));
rowElement.appendChild(cellElement);
        });
table.appendChild(rowElement);
      });

resultsDiv.appendChild(table);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search Contacts</h1>
<label for="contactNumber">Contact Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="contactNumber">
<button onclick="searchContact()">Search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>

So, I am not sure why the data is not diplayed.
Below is an example from execution log that the data is extracted correctly










Aug 7, 2024, 5:53:24 PM
Info
Filtered Data: [["2024-08-03T17:21:04.450Z","golam.imran@bproperty.com","Test Type of Request","Test Update For","test Customer 12",92872772728,"Commercial Sale",344432,"Test input 21","Email","Email"]]




Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions on this site should be about a specific problem unique to programming. As it's written, the question needs to be narrower. Please make it more specific. I suggest you study the code included, then if there is something you need help understanding about a particular part, focus your question on it.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! An answer has been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.

With all the information and codes you have given, I tried my best to replicate the issue on my end. After some time of experimentation, I found out that the results are not displayed when there is formatting present on the timestamp column, which was probably automatically putted by Google Sheets.
To resolve the issue, I modified your code, specifically the code.gs, so that all data is transformed into plain text before utilization for easier handling, and it works on my end.
The code below is the updated version of yours.
code.gs
function searchSheets(contactNumber) {
var oldSheetId = '<Place the appropriate sheet ID here>';
var newSheetId = '<Place the appropriate sheet ID here>';

var oldSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(oldSheetId).getSheetByName('OLD');
var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSheetId).getSheetByName('2024');

 //Added setNumberFormat('@STRING@') to convert the data into plain text.
var oldData = oldSheet.getDataRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@').getValues();
var newData = newSheet.getDataRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@').getValues();

var combinedData = oldData.concat(newData);

var filteredData = combinedData.filter(function(row) {
return row[5].toString() === contactNumber.toString();
  });

Logger.log('Filtered Data: ' + JSON.stringify(filteredData));

return filteredData;
}

function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
function searchContact() {
const contactNumber = document.getElementById('contactNumber').value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayResults).searchSheets(contactNumber);
    }

function displayResults(data) {
console.log('Received data:', data); // Add this for debugging
const resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
resultsDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results

if (data.length === 0) {
resultsDiv.innerHTML = '<p>No results found.</p>';
return;
      }

const table = document.createElement('table');
table.border = 1;

const headers = [
        'Timestamp', 'Submitted By', 'Type of Request', 'Update For (LM Name/Team Name)', 
        'Customer Name', 'Customer Mobile No', 'Query Type', 'Lead Number', 
        'Remarks', 'Source Name', 'Location Name'
      ];

const headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
headers.forEach(header => {
const th = document.createElement('th');
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(header));
headerRow.appendChild(th);
      });
table.appendChild(headerRow);

data.forEach(row => {
const rowElement = document.createElement('tr');
row.forEach(cell => {
const cellElement = document.createElement('td');
cellElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cell));
rowElement.appendChild(cellElement);
        });
table.appendChild(rowElement);
      });

resultsDiv.appendChild(table);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search Contacts</h1>
<label for="contactNumber">Contact Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="contactNumber">
<button onclick="searchContact()">Search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>

